# "Access is Denied" CreateFile() on Usb stick

Tags: c++, winapi, low-level

My goal is to read all bytes of an USB stick.

I tryed to open "D:" with `CreateFile()` and `fopen()` but an ERROR is raised :

> "Access is Denied"

```cpp
HANDLE disk = CreateFile("D:", 
                         GENERIC_READ,
                         FILE_SHARE_READ,        
                         NULL,
                         OPEN_EXISTING,
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                         NULL);

    if (disk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf ("%d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
```

This code prints 5 (="Access is Denied").

I'm using Windows 8 and C++.

Can someone explain to me why an error is raised ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file path is invalid.

To open the device with the letter *D*, you should use the following path:

`"\\.\D:"`

This is explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)